# Adding author name in Eclipse automatically to existing files

Tags: java, eclipse, header, javadoc

Is there a real easy to use tool (no monster tool) that I can plug into Eclipse, and press a "generate header" button and then the authors name appears in every file in that project?

Comment: Note: Author reports that the files already exist. Eclipse Code Templates don't solve this problem.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Actually in Eclipse Indigo thru Oxygen, you have to go to the Types template `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code templates -> (in right-hand pane) Comments -> double-click Types` and make sure it has the following, which it should have by default:

```
/**
 * @author ${user}
 *
 * ${tags}
 */
```

and as far as I can tell, there is nothing in Eclipse to add the javadoc automatically to existing files in one batch. You could easily do it from the command line with `sed` & `awk` but that's another question.

If you are prepared to open each file individually, then selected the class / interface declaration line, e.g. public class AdamsClass { and then hit the key combo <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and that will insert a new javadoc comment above, along with the author tag for your user. To experiment with other settings, go to `Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates`.

Comment: **ADDING HELP**

To find the `Comments ->Types` Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code templates` in the window will appear the `Comments` drop-down

Comment: thanks @Universe - now updated.

Comment: Very useful. There are any shortcut to sign the method?? Thanks!

Comment: after I make these changes, is there a way to retrospectively generate authorship comments at the top in older java files ?

Answer (score 46):

To old files I don't know how to do it... I think you will need a script to go thru all files and add the header.

To change the new ones you can do this.

Go to Eclipse menu bar

1. Window menu.
2. Preferences
3. search for Templates
4. go to Code templates
5. click on +code
6. Click on New Java files
7. Click Edit
8. add

> /**
>        ${user}
>       */

And it's done every new File will have your name on it !

Comment: This question is for files that already exist.

Answer (score 36):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> will help you add author name in existing file.

To add author name automatically, 
go to *Preferences* **-->** *[java](/questions/tagged/java)* **-->** *Code Style* **-->** *Code Templates*

[image: Preferences -- Java -- Code Style -- Code Templates]

in case you don't find above option in new versions of Eclipse - install it from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jautodoc

Comment: shift+alt+j, that was what i was looking for :)

Comment: Thats right! Tick for `Automatically add comments...` is good for including author name in newly creating files.

Comment: For Mac user's the key combination is:  option+command+J

Answer (score 5):

You can control select all customised classes and methods, and right-click, choose "Source", then select "Generate Element Comment". You should get what you want.

If you want to modify the Code Template then you can go to Preferences -- Java -- Code Style -- Code Templates, then do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and in some cases error-prone solution:

Find Regexp: `(?sm)(.*?)([^\n]*\b(class|interface|enum)\b.*)`

Replace: `$1/**\n * \n * @author <a href="mailto:j.smith@acme.com">John Smith</a>\n */\n$2`

This will add the header to the first encountered class/interface/enum in the file. Class should have no existing header yet.

Comment: It's important to mention that if the class is annotated the JavaDoc will be placed after the annotations, which is still a valid syntax but probably will not pass PMD Checkstyles.