# Show author and revision in Label Decorations for egit (eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, spring-tool-suite

I have been searching but I failed to find a proper solution, is there any way to show the author name and revision number for GIT in eclipse, like we do in SVN.

Under the label decoration section, I do not see the option of author and revision.

[image]

EDIT:
Something similar to Subclipse or Subversive

[image]

Comment: are you looking something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958530/adding-author-name-in-eclipse-automatically-to-existing-files) ?

Comment: No, I am specifically looking for EGIT perspective similar to subclipse or subversive.

Comment: maybe we should create a feature request in EGit.